# Problem connecting pyspark to MS-SQL Database

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to connect to an MS-SQL database using pyspark:

```
"jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=xxx") \
.option("dbtable", "xxx") \

    .option("user", "xxx") \
    .option("password", "xxx").load()"
```

but I get the following error

```
Error occurring post execution is: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Hi, could you please try adding the option for the driver to the query? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048728/3433323), e.g. `.option("driver" , "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") `

Comment: Additionally, do you have the driver in path? If not, download it from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11774 and include it as a jar

Comment: Thanks @mkaran, one small question should this jar file be placed on server I am hitting?

Comment: :) The jar should be somewhere accessible from all nodes, I _think_ if you place it on the master and use the `-jar path/to/jar/actual.jar`, then the jar will be copied to all nodes, so it should work.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if it all worked ok :)

Comment: Did it work? I am facing similar error while trying to write.

Comment: Yes it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy driver in folder where your python script is and you have to define it with  `.set` option like this:

```
.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar")
```

Full code for spark context, connection to ms sql and select of 1 table from ms sql could look like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext

appName = "PySpark SQL Server Example - via JDBC"
master = "local"
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) \
    .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

# Loading data from a JDBC source
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://188.188.188.188:10004;databaseName=dbnme") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.tablename") \
    .option("user", "usernmame") \
    .option("password", "pawwrod") \
    .load()
```

You can follow [this](https://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/connect-to-sql-server-in-spark-pyspark) tutorial to set connection to MS SQL properly.